# Couchbase view with composite keys : How to set the right startkey/endkey range?

Tags: view, couchbase

Having this document structure:

```
"document":{
    "title":"Cheese ",
     "start_date": "2010-02-17T15:35:00",
     "source": "s_source1"
}
```

I would like to create a view that return all documents ids between 2 dates and for a certain source:

```
function (doc, meta) {
      emit([doc.start_date,doc.source], null);
}
```

I tried to use this range key to get all document of source 1 between "2014-04-04" and "2014-04-05":

```
startkey=["2014-04-04","s_source1"]&endkey=["2014-04-05","s_source1"]
```

But this don't work for the sources. It retrieves me all document for the date range but for all sources ( s_source1,s_source2,...) .

I guess that the underscore is the source of problem( some encoding issue)?

How should I set my key range to get only documents of a unique source for a certain date range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you reverse your compound key then you'll be able to do the select, keys sort from left to right in Couchbase.

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(meta.type == "json") {
    if(doc.start_date && doc.source) {
      emit([doc.source,dateToArray(doc.start_date)],null);    
    }
  } 
}
```

To select all documents with a source value of: "s_source1" since a date in 2010 until the present day you'd have your keys like so:

```
Start_Key: ["s_source1",[2010,2,18,15,35,0]]
End_key:   ["s_source1",[2014,2,18,15,35,0]]
```

This question on the Couchbase website has some fantastic explanations of compound key sorting, I'd thoroughly recommend reading it: http://www.couchbase.com/communities/q-and-a/couchbase-view-composite-keys

Plus here is an informative section from the official documentation: http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.0/#selecting-information